# Element 'argument': The type definition is abstract and The state object to be removed is not the first in the list

Tags: layout, xml, magento-2.2.5, exception

I'm throwing this error on my /success/ page and it seems like such a generic error. It looks like further down the trace it's pointing to stuff like GoogleTagManager and other third-party modules associated with checkout but I've disabled nearly everything and it still fires this exception on checkout.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'argument': The type definition is abstract.
Line: 1024

Internal error: xmlSchemaXPathProcessHistory, The state object to be removed is not the first in the list.
Line: 1022


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'argument': The type definition is abstract.
Line: 1024

Internal error: xmlSchemaXPathProcessHistory, The state object to be removed is not the first in the list.
Line: 1022

#0 /chroot/home/m2.staging/html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(115): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('<layout xmlns:x...')
#1 /chroot/home/m2.staging/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<layout xmlns:x...', Object(Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState), Array, NULL, '/chroot/home/zt...', '%message%\nLine:...')
#2 /chroot/home/m2.staging/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#3 /chroot/home/m2.staging/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#4 /chroot/home/m2.staging/html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php(42): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
```

Now if I edit this file here like so:

protected function _initDom($xml) line 382 of vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php

```
+// Note: Ignore validations. Yes the errors/warnings should be fixed but I don't know where to fix them and just want to get things done, can fix up "Later... TM".
+$skipDomValidation = true;
+if ($skipDomValidation === false) {
    if ($this->validationState->isValidationRequired() && $this->schema) {
        $errors = $this->validateDomDocument($dom, $this->schema, $this->errorFormat);
        if (count($errors)) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException(implode("\n", $errors));
        }
    }
+}
```

Which is not good practices but it subdues the original error message and now throws this error message.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Value for key "xsi:type" is missing in the argument data.

/chroot/home/m2.staging/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Reader/Block.php(370): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Composite->evaluate(Array)
#1 /chroot/home/m2.staging/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Reader/Block.php(169): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Block->evaluateArguments(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Element), Array)
```

Such a generic error message. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

magento 2.2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just came across a similar error so here is an answer to this seemingly old question:

```xml
<type name="Vendor\Module\Model\Layer\FilterResolver">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="filterAttributes"> <!-- to the left here is the error -->
            <item xsi:type="array">
                <item xsi:type="object" name="brandfilter">brandsFilter</item>
                <item xsi:type="object" name="modelfilter">modelFilter</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Just add a `xsi:type` to the `argument` tag. In the above case, this will look like this:

```xml
<type name="Vendor\Module\Model\Layer\FilterResolver">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="filterAttributes" xsi:type="array">
            <item xsi:type="array">
                <item xsi:type="object" name="brandfilter">brandsFilter</item>
                <item xsi:type="object" name="modelfilter">modelFilter</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

---

For your very special case: I think it already gives you the line where something went wrong: `1024` - unfortunately this doesn't include the filename. Look into a `di.xml` that you've changed recently.

This is a general issue with this type of error output. If you still got issues to find the argument, use the following xpath expression:

```
//argument[not(@xsi:type)]
```